# Is there any way to make free skype calls from HTC Desire?

Tags: htc-desire, voip, skype

Well [Fring is blocked](http://www.fring.com/blog/?p=2322). I'm located in China. I neeeeed to make free skype calls to my family around the world. Skype Lite is not an option, has anybody cracked this cookie?

Comment: Your best bet is to wait for Fring to solve it's issues with Skype

Answer (score 2):

You could try out [Nimbuzz](http://www.nimbuzz.com/en).

Answer (score 2):

At the time this question was originally asked, Skype Lite was the only official Skype client and it was locked into the Verizon Network and it locked voice calling to wifi only (so as not to compete with their cell minute plans).  As of early October, Skype released it to the Market for phones on other carriers.  It was still crippled from making SkypeOut calls over the 3G connection, until a Hacker over at Droid Forums came up with a [solution](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/xeudoxus/78843-apks-unlocked-apps.html) and as I was typing this I realize that it was only for phones in the US, so it looks like it's still a no go.  **Sebastiaan's answer, Nimbuzz is your best bet.**

Comment: That doesn't really constitute an answer - a little more explanation or just plain exposition would be helpful

Comment: I can't really explain it any better than the article I linked to does.

Comment: Which was why I also said some exposition would have done.  I understand that the answer you linked explains it best but it doesn't make a good answer on here.

Comment: Fair enough.  I suppose I was being a little lazy and now it appears it didn't actually answer the question at all.  Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is uninstall the latest version of Skype and install an older version. I recently had to do this as I found the most recent versions of Skype were just bloatware and couldn't even do basic stuff (like voice chat) anymore.

Now I have to warn you that you are taking a risk installing a non-Market app, but I believe that Freewarelovers is a reputable site.

1. Uninstall your current version of Skype. Just go to Market, My Apps,
   Skype, Uninstall.
2. Switch on Settings, Applications, Unknown Sources.
3. Download version 1.0.0.984 from this link http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/app/skype#old_versions
4. When the download is finished, just install it.
5. Remember to turn off Unknown Sources afterwards.

Try version 1.0.0.984 for starters. If that doesn't work keep trying earlier versions!